# DataTables add 2 buttons inside a cell

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm pretty new in working with Datatables and I'm trying to add a new column with two buttons on each cell: a red one with text 'No' on it, that appears anytime and on click does something and a green one with 'OK' text that appears only when ColB minus ColA is +/-10 and on click does something else.
My datatable looks something like:

```
table = $("#datatable-buttons").DataTable({
            data: document.pvm.tableContent(),
            columns: [
            { data: "DateTime", title: "Date\Time" },
            { data: "ColA", title: "ColA" },
            { data: "ColB", title: "ColB" },
            { data: "", title: "Buttons" }
            ],
            fixedHeader: true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 100, 200], [10, 20, 100, 50]],
            "iDisplayLength": 20,
            fixedHeader: true,
            dom: "lfrtiBp",
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            buttons: [
              {
                  extend: "copy",
                  className: "btn-sm"
              },
              {
                  extend: "csv",
                  className: "btn-sm"
              },
              {
                  extend: "excel",
                  className: "btn-sm"
              },
              {
                  extend: "pdf",
                  className: "btn-sm"
              },
              {
                  extend: "print",
                  className: "btn-sm"
              },
            ],
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": -1,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<button color='red'>Click!</button>"
             } ]
            }
        });
```

I've tried first by adding the red button but it doesn't work :( Is there a way to add those two buttons?

Update:
document.pvm.tableContent() looks something like: 
2018-02-15 03:24     10      5
2018-02-14 03:27       7      17
In this situation the first column has just the red button and the second one both buttons

Comment: just build it on your html table. or you can share what the return of `document.pvm.tableContent()`

Comment: @plonknimbuzz If helps, I've updated my question

Comment: thats really basic right? you just build your html table then let datatables js change the table into datatables style. still not solve yet?

Comment: Done that! Thanks for the suggestion :) Sorry for not answering

Comment: im really glad to hear that. im sorry too to not give direct answer, because this is really basic and im affraid you expect more than that (basic)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realized how easy it was. Thanks a lot for your help!